# How to remove duplicates automatically in excel?

Tags: excel, duplicates, copying

I have two files, File A and File B.

- I copied File A, **Column A**'s data into File B, Column A
- I want to remove Duplicate Values from **Column A** when I paste into File B (without using VBA would be much better).

Thank you

Comment: Or the other option that I am using Countif to count the total values in Column A but is it possible to add additional criteria in Countif function to count only unique values?

Comment: You'll need to use VBA for that.

Comment: This is not a programming question.  You are actively trying to avoid writing code.  You might get some better help on SuperUser for this.

Comment: @Buggabill I am new to this how can I move this to SuperUser?

Answer (score 1):

Select Column A data and goto 'Data' menu and inside this menu you will find 'Remove Duplicates' button. Click this and it will delete duplicate rows.

Comment: Hi, Thank you but I know this option I am trying to do so when I paste the list into Column A, only unique values paste.

Comment: That's not a built-in feature.  You'll have to code for that.